# Decentraland project not starting properly

Tags: node.js, decentraland, decentraland-ecs

I am trying to run 'dcl start' command from the terminal. The Decentraland Preview webpage opens and terminal says 'Acquring comms connection'. But after that it gives the error below:

`Oops, it seems the catalyst isn't working well. [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request 127.0.0.1:8000/lambdas/collections/wearables?collectionId=urn:decentraland:off-chain:base-avatars to https://peer.decentraland.org/ [ECONNRESET] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors) Oops, it seems the catalyst isn't working well. [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request 127.0.0.1:8000/lambdas/collections/wearables?wearableId=urn:decentraland:off-chain:base-avatars:elegant_striped_shirt&wearableId=urn:decentraland:off-chain:base-avatars:elegant_blue_trousers&wearableId=urn:decentraland:off-chain:base-avatars:f_m_sandals&wearableId=urn:decentraland:off-chain:base-avatars:modern_hair&wearableId=urn:decentraland:off-chain:base-avatars:f_mouth_04 to https://peer.decentraland.org/ [ECONNRESET] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors) [HPM] ECONNRESET: Error: socket hang up at connResetException (node:internal/errors:704:14) at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:505:23) at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35) at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) { code: 'ECONNRESET' }`

What could cause this error ?

Comment: I couldn't be able to fix that issue but I could be able to run it and continue developing by making a new project and transfer the necessary files into that project.